# Why does my Systemd command fail but I can execute it manually?

Tags: systemd

I can run the following command from my shell without issue

```
sudo -u ktrl /home/andrew/.cargo/bin/ktrl -d /dev/input/event3
```

However, when I try to make a service:

/etc/systemd/system/ktrl.service

```
[Unit]
Description=ktrl

[Service]
User=ktrl
Environment=HOME=/opt/ktrl
ExecStart=/home/andrew/.cargo/bin/ktrl -d /dev/input/event3
  
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I get the following error from `systemctl status ktrl.service`

```
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/ktrl.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2020-06-27 10:35:08 EDT; 5s ago
    Process: 23335 ExecStart=/home/andrew/.cargo/bin/ktrl -d /dev/input/event3 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 23335 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 5ms

Jun 27 10:35:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started ktrl.
Jun 27 10:35:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[23335]: ktrl.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
Jun 27 10:35:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[23335]: ktrl.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/andrew/.cargo/bin/ktrl: Permission denied
Jun 27 10:35:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: ktrl.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jun 27 10:35:08 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: ktrl.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I'm executing the command `sudo -u ktrl /home/andrew/.cargo/bin/ktrl -d /dev/input/event3` as andrew. However, even if I switch to ktrl `sudo su ktrl` and run the command `/home/andrew/.cargo/bin/ktrl -d /dev/input/event3` it still works

Results of running `ll -d`:

in `/home/andrew`

```
drwxr-xr-x. 39 andrew andrew 4.0K Jun 27 12:06 .
```

in `/home/andrew/.cargo`

```
drwxrwxr-x. 4 andrew andrew 4.0K Jun 25 16:11 .
```

in `/home/andrew/.cargo/bin`

```
drwxrwxr-x. 2 andrew andrew 4.0K Jun 25 16:11 .
```

Result of running `ls -l` in `/home/andrew/.cargo/bin`

```
total 1552
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 andrew andrew 1579608 Jun 25 16:11 ktrl
```

Comment: Are you executing it manually as the user `andrew`?

Comment: I'm executing the command `sudo -u ktrl /home/andrew/.cargo/bin/ktrl -d /dev/input/event3` as andrew. However, even if I switch to ktrl `sudo su ktrl` and run the command `/home/andrew/.cargo/bin/ktrl -d /dev/input/event3` it still works

Comment: Run `ll -d` on `/home/andrew` and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was caused by SELinux. I disabled it and now everything is working.

Edit: A better solution is to move the bin to `/usr/local/bin/ktrl` and to update the ktrl.service file accordingly. This way it will still work with SELinux enabled.

Comment: There's surely a better compromise solution than disabling SELinux altogether.

Comment: @JeffSchaller

SeLinux has never been user-friendly and unfortunately remains so.

Comment: There are also better ways than having software executed from a home directory and giving 777 permissions to its binary.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Security has never been user-friendly. And to some serious degree that will always be the case.